# postgres connection refused in ubuntu

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu, service, database-connection

getting an error while connecting remotely and the error says something like

could not connect to server: Connection timed out (0x0000274C/10060) Is the server running on host x and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?

please help me out

Comment: please take a look to the output of this command: `netstat -lp` on the server where postgresql should be running.

Comment: **Connection timed out** always almost means that a firewall blocks the connection.

Comment: Can you connect on the server (local)? Try logging as postgres user on a shell and execute psql: `su - postgres -c psql`. And check the value of `listen_address` on postgresql.conf, should be `*` or the IP.

Answer (score 2):

Open your terminal and write

```
service postgresql status
```

If it says it is not running than write

```
service postgresql start
```

If the service is already running then check the listening port of your postgresql service via

```
netstat -an | grep postgresql
```

and the result will show the port it is listening.And then you can connect your database with the command

```
psql -h localhost -p port_you_found -U postgres
```

Comment: `netstat -an | grep postgresql` returned nothing. Now what?